# I am trying to make a front that has a button to pick an image from gallery and replace it with the current one

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am having a hard time trying to make the pick from gallery button work, I tried so many tutorials and videos, and IDK what I am doing wrong, please help me solve this.
I just started with flutter and this was the one thing that I couldn't solve.

[The image of the interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkZvR.png)

```
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //key for form
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height= MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation:0,
           brightness: Brightness.light,
           backgroundColor:Colors.white,
           leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined,size: 20,color: Colors.black),
           title:Text('Enregistrer',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,color:Colors.blue),textAlign:TextAlign.right),
        ),

    body: SingleChildScrollView(

      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20 ),

      child: Form(
          key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children:<Widget> [
          Column(
           children:  [

            if(Image ==null ?(Image.asset("images/emilia.jpeg",height: 150,width: 150))):null,
              pickImage != null ? FileImage(pickImage): null,


          Row(
            children:[
            OutlineButton.icon(
             icon:Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined,color:Colors.black),
              onPressed: (){pickImage(ImageSource.camera);},
              label: Text('Appareil photo',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0)),

            ),
              OutlineButton.icon(
                icon:Icon(Icons.photo_album_rounded,color:Colors.black),
                onPressed: (){pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);},
                label: Text('ouvrir la Gallerie',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0)),
              )
            ]
          ),
      ],
          ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

          children:<Widget> [
            Text('nom',
                textAlign:TextAlign.left),
            SizedBox(width:2.0),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'nom',
                hintText: 'Entrer votre nom',
              ),
                validator:(value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty || !RegExp(r'^[a-z A-Z]+$').hasMatch(value!));
                  return "entrer votre nom";
                }
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see a simple example:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  XFile? file;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            file != null
                ? Center(
                    child: Image.file(
                      File(file!.path),
                      width: 159,
                      height: 159,
                    ),
                  )
                : const Text('placeholder'),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.camera,
                    );
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    file = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery,
                    );
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.photo_album),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result: Make sure to grant camera and storage access

[image]